# How does that switch case work in JS? What does mean switch(true)?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am currently working on project, where are parts of code that I don't understand. One of them you can see below (written in JS):

```
  switch (true) {
    case parseInt(data):
      return 'data';

    case parseInt(row):
      return 'row';

    default:
      return 'default';
  }
```

I created JSFiddle to test this switch(true) statement and to see how it behaves. It always returns 'default' string. Can someone explain to me what is happening there, please?
[JSFiddle switch test](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/90436/)

Comment: It compares the case with the switch: is `true` equal to `parseInt(data)` ?

Comment: `switch` makes an identity check, which is the check with `===`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A switch in JavaScript simply compares if the value of the `case` is strictly equal (`===`) to what’s inside the `switch` (in this case `true`). This is usually used to compare strings, but booleans would also work, although it is less common. Take the following example:

```
switch (true) {
    case 1 + 1 === 3:
        return 'A';
    case 2 * 2 === 4:
        return 'B';
    default:
        return 'C';
}
```

This code would return `'B'` as it is the first case to match `true`. If none of the cases would match `true`, it would return `'C'`.

---

Regarding your specific scenario; I would recommend rewriting your code to the following:

```
if (parseInt(data) === true) {
    return 'data';
}

if (parseInt(row) === true) {
    return 'row';
}

return 'default';
```

This code does the exact same thing as yours, but it is immediately clear to the reader what is happening.

I am not sure what your goal is with this function, so I cannot recommend the best way to solve your problem. Although, I can explain to you why it might not be working.

The `parseInt` function will always return a number or `NaN` (in case the input cannot be parsed). Although a number can be truthy, it will never be strictly `true`. That's why your function always returns `'default'`. Again, I don't know what your goal is, but you *might* want to check if the value is truthy instead of `true`:

```
if (parseInt(data)) {
    // Data can be parsed to a number and is not 0 
    return 'data';
}

if (parseInt(row)) {
    // Row can be parsed to a number and is not 0
    return 'row';
}

return 'default';
```

Comment: Good explanation @Duncan Luk....In your case OP, the switch statement is looking for `parseInt(data)` or `parseInt(row)` to return true.  Otherwise the default case is called.  This is not good, btw, as "The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer."  parseInt() does not return a Boolean.

Comment: So is it possible, that code in my example have no chance to work?

Comment: @ptyskju I have updated my answer to explain why your code is not working. I hope it solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

It'll execute the first `case` that evaluates to `true`. If no `case` is `true`, it'll execute the `default` block

For example:

```js
switch (true) {
  case 1 === 1:
    console.log('ok1');
    break;
  case 2 === 2:
    console.log('ok2');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('not ok');
}
```

will `console.log('ok1')`